# How did humans in different regions evolve so differently?

Tags: science-based, biology, evolution

Google is about as helpful as a mouse trying to catch a piano, since it's listed websites that aren't very clear or informative.

So: How did humans evolve to be so different from one another? Say, Asians to Europeans.

I'd like to know since I need to be able to understand what the evolutionary factors were and how they influenced human evolution in order to determine how I should design the people living in particular areas.

Comment: Wrong site this is for designing fictional worlds, you need biology.se I think. Althoug we may be able to help we won't know as well as them.

Comment: Humans aren't all that different from one another. Just look at dogs.

Comment: I guess this might be useful: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/14414/do-humans-have-enough-biological-differences-to-be-grouped-into-races-or-subspec . It short, the humans haven't even evolved too differently; there are just several distinct phenotypic markers. The animals could give far better examples of evolutionary adaptations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How did humans evolve to be so different from one another?

Actually, humans aren't very different from each other. The races differ in extremely superficial characteristics.

Lighter skinned individuals absorb more UV light to produce the necessary Vitamin D that equatorial people (such strong sunlight) get easily. Dark skinned individuals are more common where protection fron UV light is most needed.

The evolution of humans is no different - in any way - than the evolution of any other plant or animal. There is a niche; there is an advantage to a mutation in that niche; there are more people with that gene.

Sickle-cell anemia trait and disease is an example of this. Is it a racial difference?

Lactose tolerance after infancy is an example of a genetic mutation that swept Europe. Is it a racial difference?

I don't think so. I think these were mutations which helped the population in the niche. Like any other evolutionary "selection".

The human genome has been completely sequenced. The difference between races is almost infinitesimally small.